# Confused about Content provider contenturi and content provider authorities tag

Tags: android, android-contentprovider

from [google](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/content-provider-creating.html#ContentURI) example below

```
As an example of designing and coding content URI handling, consider a provider with the authority com.example.app.provider that recognizes the following content URIs pointing to tables:

content://com.example.app.provider/table1: A table called table1.
content://com.example.app.provider/table2/dataset1: A table called dataset1.
content://com.example.app.provider/table2/dataset2: A table called dataset2.
content://com.example.app.provider/table3: A table called table3.
```

I am confused here. Does this example mean that Table1Contentprovider, Table2ContentProvider, Table3ContentProvider are pointing at the same authority url? From what I read, each provider should have unique authority url.

Or does it mean, there is only one provider here that works all 3 tables? If that is the case, in the query method of the provider do we run sql query to get data related to all three tables?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> from google example below

Actually, it is from [this page](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/content-provider-creating.html#ContentURI), not the one you linked to.

> Does this example mean that Table1Contentprovider, Table2ContentProvider, Table3ContentProvider are pointing at the same authority url?

There is only one provider, not three ("consider ***a*** provider").

> From what I read, each provider should have unique authority url.

A `ContentProvider` can support multiple authorities, via a comma-delimited list in the `android:authorities` attribute, though most of the time they only support one.

> Or does it mean, there is only one provider here that works all 3 tables?

Correct.

> If that is the case, in the query method of the provider do we run sql query to get data related to all three tables?

In methods like `query()`, you examine the `Uri` that you are supplied and perform the operations specific to the supplied path. In the aforementioned example, `query()` would look to do different things for the paths `table1`, `table2/dataset1`, `table2/dataset2`, and `table3`.